# How to get the month as string in timestamp in Ruby

Tags: ruby, timestamp

I need to get the following timestamp format: "December 13, 2012 2:29:44 PM PST"

```
time_stamp = Time.now
time = time_stamp.strftime("%m %d, %Y %H:%M:%S %p PST")
time # => "12 13, 2012 14:29:44 PM PST"
```

How do I get the month string in place of integer and also hours corrected to 2 ?

Answer (score 4):

You really should have tried googling this first. I found this under the first result for ruby date format:

http://www.dzone.com/snippets/date-time-format-ruby

```
time = time_stamp.strftime("%B %d, %Y %I:%M:%S %p %Z")

 => "December 13, 2012 02:49:18 PM PST"
```

Also, you should `%Z` instead of PST to ensure you're in the right time zone.

Comment: thanks!..I just did it while waiting for answer..I found at http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_date_time.htm.

Comment: Feel free to mark mine as the answer if I was able to help you.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the documentation here http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/date/rdoc/DateTime.html#method-i-strftime

for 12 based hour use `%l` and for month use `%B`

```
time_stamp = Time.now
time = time_stamp.strftime("%B %d, %Y %l:%M:%S %p PST")
time # => "December 13, 2012 2:29:44 PM PST"
```

Answer (score 0):

The website you are looking for is: http://www.foragoodstrftime.com/

It contains all the options you can pass to `strftime` and you build your own ones with ease.

Comment: This is cool but seems borderline excessive. Thanks for the share though.

Comment: Actually, after looking at the complete listing for strftime available [here](http://lostincode.net/posts/strtime-ruby-osx) it doesn't seem so crazy.